# Python Find and Replace/Append in CSV from Dic

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with four columns. One of those columns (the third one) are IP addresses. Those IP's belong to certain companies. I'm trying to find instances of IP addresses, and APPEND the company name to the end of the IP address.

Example of CSV

```
   Time,Origination,IP Address, Destination
    6/11/14 14:45,1234567890,1.2.3.4,0987654321
```

What I would like:

```
    Time,Origination,IP Address, Destination
    6/11/14 14:45,1234567890,1.2.3.4 **"CUSTOMERNAME"**,0987654321
```

THis is my code... it's a mess.

```
    import pandas
    import xlrd
    import csv
    import os

    def replace_ip(file, dic):
        spoofingFile = open('spoofing.csv','wb')
        wr = csv.writer(spoofingFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for i, j in dic.iteritems():

    ^^^^ I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS! ^^^^^^        


    def csv_from_excel():

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Python27\\Work\\spreadsheet.xlsx")
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
        spoofingFile = open('spoofing.csv', 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(spoofingFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
            wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

        spoofingFile.close()


    csv_from_excel()
    df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Python27\\Work\\spoofing.csv')
    df = df.sort("Orig IP Address")
    headers = ["InviteTime (Oracle)","Orig Number","Orig IP Address","Dest Number"]
    df.to_csv('output.csv', cols=headers, index=False)
    os.remove("c:\\python27\\work\\spoofing.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a replace function not work?

```
def replace_ip(path,ip,name):
    fin = open(path)
    inserted = [i.replace(ip,ip+name) for i in fin.readlines()]
    fin.close()
    fout = open(path,"w")
    fout.write("\n".join(inserted))
    fout.close()
#example
#replace_ip("test.csv","1.2.3.4","COMPANYNAME")
```